# Azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Hi everyone I want to put column values in data flow dynamically in azure data factory any one can help me in this

Activity name is windows or aggregate function in any one i just want to give dynamic column names instead of manual feeding

Please help me

I have multiple files in my adls now i need to process them without using adb(azure data factory) and i need to remove duplicate from them and then paste them in adls again and for achieving this I need only one data flow where I can put column names dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dataflow, you can use the `columns()` function which returns an array of all the output columns for the current stream. Thus, you do not want to specify the columns manually in group by of aggregate transformation. Below is the approach to remove duplicates from the source.

- Take the source transformation with input dataset from ADLS.
- Then take the aggregate transformation.
- In group by of aggregate settings, enter `sha2(256,columns())`. This will take all the incoming columns and generate a hash.
- Then in Aggregates, **+ Add column pattern** near column1 and then delete Column1. Then Enter **true()** in matching condition. Then click on undefined column expression and enter `$$` in **column name expression** and `first($$)` in **value expression**.

[image: gif1]

**Dataflow script for aggregate transformation:**

```
aggregate(groupBy(groupcol =  sha2(256,columns())),
each(match(true()), $$  =  first($$))) ~> aggregate1
```

**Sample Input data for aggregate transformation:**
[image]

**Output of aggregate transformation**
[image]

- Duplicates are removed without giving the column names manually.
- Then you can use select transformation and remove the extra column `groupcol` (hash generated from `aggregate transformation`) and copy the data back to ADLS using sink transformation.

**Reference**: **MS document**   [data flow script for distinct row using all columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#distinct-row-using-all-columns)

Comment: Hi Aswin thanks for giving me the solution but in case pf 200 columns or even more then that it will increase time drastically and that we can afford tbats why we want to give column name manually , alsp can you give me the same tutorial for how to remove the column dynamicaaly not manually

Comment: how to remove the column dynamically not manually? - **Which column needs to be removed? Could you explain it in detail?**